# How to unlock 3TB HDD for Asrock X58 Extreme

Tags: hard-drive

I want to use my new Seagate Barracuda 3TB HDD.
Since my mainboard does not have an UEFI BIOS I can not use the whole storage capacity.
How can I unlock it?

I already tried this utility without success: http://www.asrock.com/feature/3TB/index.asp

I'm running Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: Is your motherboard on the list of supported boards listed in the link you provided?  Which one is it?  Does your motherboard model purport to support 3TB+ sized drives? Are you running your latest BIOS? Are you trying to boot from the drive or just access it as a secondary, non-system drive?  When you say you "can not use the whole storage capacity", do you mean you can see SOME of the drive?  What capacity does the BIOS report the drive as?  What does Windows see the drive as (if at all)?

Comment: I use a SSD as my boot drive. The Barracuda is for media storage. The BIOS was up-to-date, but reported a size of just about 700GB. I was only able to format it to 700GB in Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to re-format it as GPT in order to use the whole storage capacity.

Since Asrock did not provide a readme file it was hard to guess.